# Event bubbling - does the Event get cloned?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

When a event gets dispatched on a nested child with bubbling set to true, does the Event object itself get cloned for every display object that the event hits while 'bubbling' across the display stack? For example, does the Event.ENTER_FRAME event object get cloned for every display object that's on the scene?

On a broad level, I'm trying to determine when Event.clone() occurs and where it can be a performance issues with too many event objects slowing down garbage collection.

Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer, I was wrong! :O I swear that never happens. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Simple answer, yes the event always gets cloned. See [the documentation to confirm](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#clone%28%29).</strike>
My original answer was wrong. The event does not always get cloned. As @weltraumpirat pointed out, the documentation says this only happens when you manually redispatch the event. It's impossible to know how many classes (if any) that Adobe has written do this, but it is possible that some do. Still my answer "always gets cloned" was wrong.

However, that doesn't mean that events are not the issue with your performance. They only get cloned if you re-dispatch an existing event, but if not, they still get dispatched as a new instance, which is exactly what the clone method is doing anyway.

Finally, we can see in the Tamarin source code, specifically in globals.as, the implementation of the `dispatchEvent` method:

```
public function dispatchEvent(event:Event):Boolean  {
    if (event.target && event.target!=null) {
        return dispatchEventFunction (event.clone());
    } else {
        return dispatchEventFunction (event);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the cloning happens here based on whether certain event properties are populated. I have not yet found the code where the target property gets populated, but at any rate there  you have it. The clone method is only called where an existing event is re-dispatched (at least from what we can see). I stand corrected. :)

As a side note, I think this is a major flaw in the flash player. Adobe should have made this a special case in the VM where internally, it's just a pointer that get's passed around instead of cloning every single time the event is needed somewhere, especially given that the base-design of the AVM2 is an event-driven system.

Comment: Not that I seriously doubt what you're saying, especially about bubbling being a major flaw in the player... But the documentation only refers to those occasions when you manually redispatch the event using `dispatchEvent (event)`.  How do you know it occurs "behind the scenes" when bubbling?

Comment: @weltraumpirat I have to say, I really like you. You force me to challenge my assumptions and actually get some concrete evidence. lol. Let me poke around in the Tamarin source code for a few minutes and I'll let you know for sure.

Comment: I keep thinking the same about you :)

Comment: @weltraumpirat, Thanks for questioning... I was wrong.. again lol. It's interesting because this means that dispatching completely new events is far more expensive than passing around cloned ones, since the properties of the event need to be populated when first created. I bet that there are many cases(internally) where Adobe has, knowing this, passed around clones instead of dispatching new ones. Something to consider when writing classes with lots of event handling for sure.

Comment: As an aside, I wrote a post about this very thing... http://www.developria.com/2009/12/can-event-performance-be-impro.html

Comment: @AmyBlankenship thanks for the article, I guess we can see now from the code I dug up from the VM that your theory is correct. It knows that you're re-using an event because the .target property was populated on a previous call. This is because the real dispatching event is dispatchEventFunction(), not dispatchEvent().